# Why "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '29/8/2013 CHAR(20)?"

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I am trying to create a table in mysql database using Python mysql connector. When try to run the program I get following error.
But getting following error.

`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '29/8/2013 CHAR(20),29/8/2013 CHAR(20),31/8/2013 CHAR(20),09-02-2013 CHAR(20),09-' at line 1`

I am not able to figure out?

Bellow is the code meant to create Table in mysql-db.
Column names of each column is some date but data in columns are characters.
But when ever trying to run program I am getting error stated above.

**Code:-**

`cursor.execute("create table ineuron.DRESS_SALE(Dress_id int(20) NOT NULL,29/8/2013 CHAR(20),29/8/2013 CHAR(20),31/8/2013 CHAR(20),09-02-2013 CHAR(20),09-04-2013 CHAR(20),09-06-2013 CHAR(20),09-08-2013 CHAR(20),09-10-2013 CHAR(20),09-12-2013 CHAR(20)")`

I hope to here from you soon.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The standard way to deal with column names that are not alphanumeric is to enclose them with backticks (\`). You are also missing the closing `)` from the end of your `create table` statement. However, even after making these changes, your attempt to create this table will still fail because you have two columns named `29/8/2013`.